# EJB 3 : An illegal attempt to commit a one phase capable resource with existing two phase capable resources has occurred

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.1, websphere-8, ejb-2.x

Recently we have migrated our EJB2 application to EJB 3.Now we are facing following error.

```
An illegal attempt to commit a one phase capable resource with existing two phase capable resources has occurred.
```

We are doing an XA datasource based transaction first, then Non-XA and finally an XA.

Seems like NON-XA after an XA is causing the issue.

This was working fine with EJB2.

Could someone help us on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using a resource that isn't two-phase XA enabled (possibly the database driver)? I'm not an expert in this, but this blog might be of use:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/trace_analysis_wtrn0063e?lang=en

Comment: That is a good link.  If your EJB 2.x application had enabled last phase optimization in its deployment descriptor, be sure that the new EJB 3.x application does the same.  This can't be configured with annotations.  The setting is called 'Last participant support'. Example: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/lao/tasks/tla_cfap2.html

Comment: LPS have some risk involved in it.so we have changed our non-XA transaction to XA to support two phase commit.now its working fine..now we need to check its impact :( ...Thank you both for the response :).